# No rule to make target in a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to build a simple LKM, and I want to set a `Makefile` that will build my module. I have a file called `module.c` and I need to create an object module of this file.

```
obj-m := module.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

**Error**

```
$ make all
make[2] No rule to make target 'module.o', needed by '__build'.
```

**Is there something wrong here?**

Comment: So make tells you that it does not know how to create `module.o`. Looking at your make file I think you should explain how you think that make should know that from what you provide. Most obviously you did not explicitly provide a rule. So what implicit mechanisms do you expect to make that unneeded?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't get you. All I can say is that both `module.c` and `Makefile` are in the same directory.

Comment: `obj-m := module.o` -> `obj-m += module.o`

Comment: Hmm, if that is all you can say then we probably need to first find out your level of understanding. Please state which of the following concepts are known to you "rule", "dependency". Please explain about your background. Did you successfully follow a few make tutorials? Can you write a basic makefile which just creates an executable by directly calling a compiler?

Comment: Your makefile invokes `make` in another directory (`/lib/modules/...`). That second invocation of `make` uses the makefile it finds there and doesn't know how to build `module.o`. If you show us the second makefile, maybe we can help you.

Comment: This is a makefile that works with the Linux kernel build system to compile kernel modules.  You should make that clear in your question, else people can't understand the makefile.  People unfamiliar with the term won't know what you mean by "LKM" and you don't have appropriate tags on your question to direct them.

Comment: Please try replacing `M=$(PWD)` with `M=$(CURDIR)` and see if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

make search for module.o in the directory you specified and did not find it, and have no rule to create that file

Answer (score 0):

Just check If your module codefile name is module.o (Extension must be .o not .c)